# Make 2d-histogram of sky coordinates

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib

I'm trying to check the angular distribution of a sample using histograms. 
What i do is read the data file as an ndarray that contains the fields with the sky coordinates ('alpha',''delta) and then i use numpy.histogram2d and imshow to make a plot.
When i compare the final plot with the range of the data i found that their different.
Here is an example code with a binning in the entire sphere :

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as pl
#Generate random catalogue
alpha=100*np.random.random(100)
delta=-30+60*np.random.random(100)
CATALOGUE=np.ndarray(shape=(100),dtype={'names':('alpha','delta'),'formats':('f8','f8')})
for i in range(100):
    CATALOGUE[i]=(alpha[i],delta[i])

print "Right Ascension interval= [%s,%s]"%(np.min(CATALOGUE['alpha']),np.max(CATALOGUE['alpha']))
print "Declination interval= [%s,%s]"%(np.min(CATALOGUE['delta']),np.max(CATALOGUE['delta']))
H, xedges, yedges = np.histogram2d(CATALOGUE['alpha'],CATALOGUE['delta'], bins=(np.arange(0,360+0.1,3.6),np.arange(-90,90+0.1,1.8)))
fig = pl.figure(figsize=(9,5))
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
im = pl.imshow(H, interpolation='none',cmap=pl.cm.gray_r,extent=[xedges[0], xedges[-1], yedges[0], yedges[-1]])
fig.colorbar(im,orientation='Horizontal')
ax.set_aspect('equal')
pl.savefig('hist_test.png')
```

When i run this the histogram is different to whats expected from the interval given by the initial data. I tried to change the binning but i don't get much better results.

What could i be doing wrong ?

Is there a way to accomplish this on a sphere projected like surface ?

Thanks for the help

Edit : Here is a very small sample of the data (with other columns removed)

321.35969128 9.93335781
322.61418111 10.14449632
325.01105374 10.53199921
325.20021403 10.49549834
325.21419238 10.41766926
325.30530102 10.56187662
325.42751521 10.44816114
325.44439994 10.47945994
325.46404052 10.56886508
325.47326548 10.53406801
325.48491199 10.54833508
325.51330280 10.52523922
325.53097826 10.66066162
325.57284098 10.59885846
325.63550236 10.60901457
325.84671192 10.68180839
325.78860114 10.65201938
325.85162465 10.54814596
325.79754828 10.54660071
325.93804346 10.62466427

Comment: Can you get the same result with small dummy data (that you can post so we can play with it)?

Comment: I tried with a small sample (posted) and i dont see difference.

Comment: Edit your code snippet to add the data so we can run it copy-and-paste, and be more specific about what you think the result should be and what it actually is.

Comment: Sorry i don't think i understand how do you want me to modify the code.
When you run this and you compare the intervals printed and the intervals form the histogram you should find that they are different i think.

Comment: We *can't* run this, you haven't put the data in the script. Put it in as a declared numpy array or something, instead of requiring `data.dat`. (Or, if you find the problem occurs with all data, make that explicit by generating random data _in the script_.)

Comment: Ok , now it runs with a random catalogue

Comment: The default x- and y-ticklabels on a imshow are the indices of the array elements in it -- note that if you change the first line to, say, `alpha=500*np.random.random(10)` the data expands vertically but the labels don't. Do you need to calculate the data values of those ticklabels?

Answer (score 2):

Would matplotlib's hist2d work for you?:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as pl

#Generate random catalogue
# Range for unif(a,b) is (b-a)*unif() + a
alpha=360*np.random.random(100) # alpha is (0,360)
delta=(90+90)*np.random.random(100) - 90 #delta is (-90,0)
CATALOGUE=np.ndarray(shape=(100),dtype={'names':('alpha','delta'),'formats':('f8','f8')})
for i in range(100):
    CATALOGUE[i]=(alpha[i],delta[i])

print "alpha interval= [%s,%s]"%(np.min(CATALOGUE['alpha']),np.max(CATALOGUE['alpha']))
print "delta interval= [%s,%s]"%(np.min(CATALOGUE['delta']),np.max(CATALOGUE['delta']))
fig = pl.figure(figsize=(9,5))
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, aspect='equal')

#Non-uniform bins:
pl.hist2d(alpha, delta, bins=[[0,20,40,45,48,52,60,80,100,200,225,250,360],[-90,-30, -12,-4,2,18,30,90]])
#Uniform bins:
#pl.hist2d(alpha, delta, bins=[np.arange(0,360,3.6),np.arange(-90,90,1.8)])
pl.colorbar()
pl.show()
```

sample result:

> ```
> alpha interval= [4.62764250657,359.013680439]
> delta interval= [-87.9255707577,88.9034353411]
> ```

[image]

Comment: Thats nice. Can you use that with variable bins ?

Comment: Yup. Example added, and it's in the docstring for hist2d, and it's the same argument numpy's histogram2d uses.

Comment: Great. I think that solves my problem for now. 
Though i dint understand well why my aproach didnt work i hope that this answer can be useful to others

Comment: Does the last comment I left on the question make sense of your np.histogram2d problem? `imshow` has its own labeling standards.

Comment: Oh sorry , i missed that comment. What happens if my data is within right ascension (300,60)=(-60,60) (for example) and i want to plot only that interval ? i tried to use a non-monotonic bin but i got an error

Comment: Your code is inconsistent (data range for alpha and delta vs. bin range), you're help-vampiring by morphing the question instead of asking a new _and more clearly defined_ one, and the comment above doesn't make much sense: (300,60) doesn't equal (-60,60) and bin edges may be non-uniform but they can't be non-monotonic.

Comment: (300,60) is equal to (-60,60) in angular coordinates. 
I agree with you that i'm being inconsistent and unclear (and i apologize for that). My original question was limited and i didn't wanted to open a new question because in reality my 'problem' wasn't solved.

Comment: Still unclear. This solution plots a range from -30 to 30; do you see how to alter it to run from -60 to 60?